# Can I have a "force close a specific app" shortcut on my screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, chrome-for-android, force-close

My Google Chrome frequently hangs for no apparent reason. Application is active (responding), but tabs are blank and nothing loads... The only solution that I found is to go into `Settings -> Apps -> Google Chrome` and "force close" it. Then I re-open it, and it works OK again, for some time.

I'd like to automate this manual "force close" process, e.g. I'd like to have a shortcut on my screen that terminates Chrome for me. Any other easy way to close Chrome is acceptable too.

My device is Asus Transformer, rooted.

Comment: You can get halfway there by adding a shortcut to apps settings.

Comment: Maybe try Dolphin Browser, it might fare better than Chrome (bear in mind Chrome is still early stages...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've ended up using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), it is trivial to create a task to kill a specific application (Google Chrome), than add a shortcut (widget) to that task on the screen.

Edit: I've actually created a task that not only kills Chrome, but restarts it afterwards as well, all in one click:

[image]

Comment: Very neat and handy app, powerful as well :) Good for you, I saw that on twitter, that there's going to be a new Tasker that will enable you to save them as "mini independant programs" outside of Tasker..

Comment: Another option that works well is [Automate](http://llamalab.com/automate/), although this requires root.

Comment: I implement such a Tasker 'Kill App' task for Whatsapp - when I want to pause it. But it does not truly "Force Close" it. That is, Whatsapp remains active, receiving messages. Is there a solution that really "Force Closes" an app, incl. its background process running?

Answer (score 1):

Get a process killing app from the market like 'Advanced Task Killer', it will allow you select which processes you would like to kill and then do so by clicking a single "kill" button.

**Warning!!** Of course forcibly "killing" a process is not recommended as it can break your application (think of what would happen if a process is writing to file and then is suddenly terminated, you could end up with a corrupt asset!!!) or even, in worse conditions, harm your system.

you will either have to wait for it to close by itself or just use a different browser. so the answer is yes, but don't do this.

Comment: Using task Killer is frowned upon, Android != Windows, where you can zap at a process to kill it a lá Windows Task Manager. You could actually end up de-stabilizing Android and... also, drain the battery, in the context of services, kill 'em, they'll end up restarting - juice sucked! which is the very nature of services. *Let Android do its job*

Comment: Hence -1 from me for recommending it. The answer is don't...use...any...task...killers...what...so...ever!

Comment: actually killing a process (pid) is a linux native method of forcibly closing a process, of course you would use it only in extreme conditions. I guess an edit is in place!

Comment: Android is not Linux! :) Don't even think it is, just because it has a limited busybox userland tools to mimick a full blown Linux desktop/server....

Comment: just trying to show the similarities. btw, edited my post, thanks guys!

Comment: @t0mm13b: Although this is not something that I would like to do (still a multi-step process), this one specific case is probably ok task for a task killer. After all, all I want to do is kill a misbehaving task quickly and effortlessly (on demand - **not** automatically).